# with which encoding is my sdcard mounted by android?

Tags: sd-card, mount, special-chars

I uploaded some music to my htc sensation (not rooted) by mounting the sdcard via usb as vfat from a desktop linux computer and copying the mp3 files and playlist files. This works fine as long as the song titles have only ascii characters. But often they have foreign characters (umlauts). So it's crucial to mount the device on my desktop with the same encoding as android mounts it, otherwise the titles looks scrambled and the playlists don't match with the song files.

So which are the mount options that android uses to mount the sdcard? 
I tried the utf8 option on the desktop but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out by issuing the command `mount` at a terminal prompt (either via `adb shell` of using any [terminal app](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=terminal%20emulator)). As I have no access to *your* sdcard, I cannot answer the question for sure (I could only tell you about *mine*, where the relevant parameters are set as `codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8`. So it's "Latin-1" (ISO-8859-1), which seems quite logical with a FAT file system, and probably is also used in your case.

Full list of options:

```
rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0002,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
```

Comment: very interesting. always thought of utf8 as something **instead** iso8859. And wasn't aware that terminal apps are available without rooting.

Comment: Sure it is *instead* – but per "object". You cannot have the same mount-point using both simultaneously, but you can well have multiple mount-points where one uses iso-8859 and the other UTF8. Both are "character sets".